# What should an unofficial transcript consist of?

Tags: transcript-of-records

My university only issues an official transcript on paper ( Will take me a month to get it). However, we have a separate student's portal where my "grade history" can be accessed. It is a list of all courses along with the grades and my CGPA, but does not contain anything more than that. Would this work while sending it to a  professor that needs to see it for grad school?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that's probably fine.  The list of courses, grades and GPA is about all that an official transcript contains anyway.

You can include a note to the professor asking them to contact you if they need anything else.

Comment: Thanks! Is it okay if it does not contain the credits of the subjects?

Comment: Probably.  You can ask the professor to let you know if they need that information.